# how to setup Clion to debug node in Clion IDE?

Tags: clion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any instruction/link to show how to setup CLion for debugging ros node? thanks for help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249712/how-to-setup-clion-to-debug-node-in-clion-ide?/) by [deliang](https://answers.ros.org/users/28758/deliang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/210534/jetbrains-clion-ide-setup-for-ros/) may or may not give you enough detail.

Once you figure out, adding an instruction on [IDEs](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs) page would be much appreciated.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0